# database/sql Exec() function fail with concatenating string

Tags: postgresql, go

A peculiar error occurred today when was manipulating data in `Postgres` using `database/sql` and driver `github.com/lib/pq`. I have the following SQL schema created in `Postgres`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bench_bytea (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR,
    data BYTEA
);
```

A very basic table containing a data blob of type `BYTEA`.

I then tried to execute simple `INSERT` statement using the `Exec()` function provided by `database/sql`. Here it is:

```golang
psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
    "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
    host, port, user, password, dbname)

db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer db.Close()

stmt := `INSERT INTO bench_bytea (id, name, data) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING`
data := `{"title": "Sleeping Beauties", "genres": ["Fiction", "Thriller", "Horror"], "published": false}`
i := 0

_, err = db.Exec(stmt, i, "testing "+string(i), []byte(data))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

The key highlight happens on the `db.Exec()` line where I execute a SQL INSERT statement *(in practicality `i` is an index of an array where I stored different testing `data`. I didn't want to include the other pieces of data here since it's really long and irrelevant)*. The error I received is:

```
pq: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

Now if I change `"testing "+string(i)` into `"testing"`, the error is gone. That is, if I didn't insert a concatenating strings into the `name` column, there's no error. What is going on here?

Comment: Use `strconv.Itoa` to convert an integer to string.

Comment: ... https://play.golang.com/p/3gZ9el8x5Fa

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type *"Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type **yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer**. "* (not the integer)

Comment: Ah... I'll answer my own question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert an integer to a string like that. The result of `string(0)` is `"\x00"`, aka a null byte, instead of `"0"` which is probably you want. You should use [`strconv.Itoa`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa) for the conversion instead.